# Is a function call within a function part of the same scope

Tags: c++, c

Does `MyNode` still exist as it's passed down through function calls, or has it gone out of scope? Is a function call within a function call part of the same scope?

```
int Foo(){
   MyNode node;
   node.a = 1;
   node.b = 2;
   return DoThings(&node);
}

int DoThings(MyNode *node){
    // use node to do great stuff
    // but does it still exist?
}
```

I'm debugging some code and it essentially crashes here, but this code is many decades old and has been working otherwise for that long, so now I am bamboozled.

Comment: Welcome to C++: if the crash happens on a particular line, it doesn't mean that the bug is on that line. It can be caused by undefined behavior at any point, during the execution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Scope is **where** in source code **identifiers** are visible. Lifetime is **when** during program execution **objects** exist.

An object like `node` with automatic storage duration is associated with execution of the block it is defined in. Its lifetime ends when execution of that block **ends**. A return statement can end the execution, and so can program control flowing to the end of the block. Calling a subroutine merely suspends execution of the block; it does not end it. The object continues to exist during the subroutine call and may be accessed by the subroutine.

Comment: So in my example, `node` still exists in `DoThings()` ?

Comment: @errno_44 yes. node will only be destroyed _after_ Foo() has returned (and therefore will be alive during the call to DoThings)

Comment: @robthebloke: `node` will cease to exist when execution of `Foo` **ends**. This can happen when `Foo` returns, but it can also happen when a `setjmp` ends it, when a subroutine calls `exit`, and possibly for other reasons.